Are $\delta$-close logical states of a code also close in terms of physical states?
If I have two logical states of a quantum code that are close in trace distance i.e. $\vert 0\rangle_L$ and $U_L\vert 0\rangle_L$ where $\|U_L - I\|_{\diamond} \leq \delta$, what is an upper bound (if any) on how close can the corresponding physical states be?

What exactly do you mean with physical state in this context? Don't you mean that the operators $U_L$ and $\mathbb I$ are $\delta$-close and aren't you interested in the distance between $\rho = |0\rangle_L \langle 0|_L$ and $\sigma = U_L|0\rangle_L \langle 0|_L U^\dagger_L$?
